# simple gradle build running compass failing

Tags: jruby, gradle, compass-sass

I have a very simple gradle project.  I am just trying to run compass.  However when I do try to run `gradle installCompass` the build fails.  I included the build script I am using.  I only have this script and a single scss file in the project.

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'compass'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/robfletcher/gradle-plugins' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jruby:jruby-complete:1.7.3'
        classpath 'org.gradle.plugins:gradle-compass:1.0.7'
    }
}
compass {
    cssDir = file('public/styles')
    sassDir = file('scss')
}
```

the error I get

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'GradleStyleGuide'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find org.jruby:jruby-complete:1.7.3..
     Required by:
         :GradleStyleGuide:unspecified
```

this is the result of a dependency check

```
compass
\--- org.jruby:jruby-complete:1.7.3 FAILED
```

Here is what happens when I run the build from command line.

```
Gradle 1.6
------------------------------------------------------------

Gradle build time: Tuesday, May 7, 2013 9:12:14 AM UTC
Groovy: 1.8.6
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
Ivy: 2.2.0
JVM: 1.7.0_17 (Oracle Corporation 23.7-b01)
OS: Windows 7 6.1 amd64

C:\Users\me>cd \code\GradleStyleGuide

C:\code\GradleStyleGuide>gradle installCompass
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.7.3/jruby-complete-1.7.3.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jruby/shared/1.7.3/shared-1.7.3.pom
Download http://dl.bintray.com/robfletcher/gradle-plugins/org/gradle/plugins/gradle-compass/1.0.7/gradle-compass-1.0.7.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.7.3/jruby-complete-1.7.3.jar
Download http://dl.bintray.com/robfletcher/gradle-plugins/org/gradle/plugins/gradle-compass/1.0.7/gradle-compass-1.0.7.jar
:installCompass FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':installCompass'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compass'.
   > Could not find org.jruby:jruby-complete:1.7.3.
     Required by:
         :GradleStyleGuide:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 10.014 secs
```

Comment: Try without `mavenLocal()`, and throw in `--refresh-dependencies` just to make sure.

Comment: I removed mavenLocal() and tried a refresh and that did not help because I do not have that task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding a wrapper task and a repository of mavenCentral, outside of buildscript I was able to get this to work.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/robfletcher/gradle-plugins' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.gradle.plugins:gradle-compass:1.0.7'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'compass'

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = "1.6"
}

compass {
    cssDir = file('public/styles')
    sassDir = file('sass')
}
```

Comment: Can this compass  be used for multiple folders? http://stackoverflow.com/q/33285167/2072569 (maybe you know this for 50 rep)

Answer (score 1):

I can resolve `jruby-complete` just fine (using your build script). Chances are that the problem is related to your environment (e.g. no proxy settings configured for Gradle). I recommend to run with `--info` and check the log output.

Comment: I was having this issue at home, and now at work.  Is it possible that something is wrong with my install of gradle? I added more info to the initial post as well. I see that it does download jruby, but it states it cannot resolve the dependency.

Comment: Hard to say. Best chance is to examine the log.

Comment: It isn't actually failing when resolving the build script class path; it's failing when the `installCompass` task tries to resolve a `compass` configuration. Maybe you haven't configured the `compass` plugin correctly? (I'm not familiar with that plugin.)

Comment: Doesnt this line indicate its with jruby?  I can check my comapss config as well. Could not find org.jruby:jruby-complete:1.7.3

Comment: The `jruby-complete` line above is for a different configuration, and may be unnecessary. You should check the `compass` *plugin* configuration.

Comment: I was not able to find anything with the plugin. Not sure what to look for.