# Gradle - build sass per productflavor (multi folder)

Tags: android, gradle, sass

We created an Android app with a webview which shows a local website from the assets folder.

The project has different Product Flavors to generate diffent apps with different styles and content but with the same codebas (native Java and HTML / JS).

For each flavor we want to define a diffent sass file with the colors and tweaks for that specific flavour.

I know that I need to create a task in gradle which builds the CSS files but I have no idea where to start:

- How do I get the url of the assets folder of a specific flavour?
- Can I use a special gradle plugin for building sass or do I have to create a task which executes the "sass" command?
- When I use another gradle plugin like compass, how do I configure the right folders for each flavour? The plugin settings are in the top level and not in the Android plugin level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finaly have the solution!

Add this to your build.gradle in the main folder (not of your app):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/robfletcher/gradle-plugins' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.github.robfletcher:compass-gradle-plugin:2.0.6'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Add this the build.gradle of the app module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.github.robfletcher.compass'

android {

[..]

    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        for (output in variant.outputs) {
            def assetsDir = output.packageApplication.assets;
            tasks["merge${variant.name.capitalize()}Assets"].doLast() {
                println "Assets folder: " + assetsDir

                def _ccsDir = file("$assetsDir/css")
                def _sassDir = file("$assetsDir/sass")
                def _imagesDir = file("$assetsDir/images")
                def _javascriptsDir = file("$assetsDir/js")
                def _fontsDir = file("$assetsDir/fonts")

                project.compass {
                    cssDir = _ccsDir
                    sassDir = _sassDir
                    imagesDir = _imagesDir
                    javascriptsDir = _javascriptsDir
                    fontsDir = _fontsDir
                }
                //compileSass
                project.compassCompile.execute()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I never thought it would work out but it works!

Comment: One big note: When you use "Generate signed APK.." this build task is not working for some reason. When I build them with the run button in a release variant with signingConfigs: the APK in 'build\outputs\apk' is ok.